# Gravar no banco apenas chekbox checados no angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como eu faço para gravar apenas checkboxes que são checados. Veja só, tenho esse exemplo e quando eu gravo está gravando os 22 itens.

```
<li>
    <label class="requerido">Profissoes</label>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in objeto.profissoes" ng-class="{'editando':item.editando}">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selecionado" ng-checked="item.checked"/>{{item.nome}}
            </li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Esse código está na minha `view`. Quanto ao `Controller` e etc, estão funcionando. Não há erros, apenas que ao gravar grava todas as profissões e não somente os checados.

Comment: De alguma forma, falta eu dizer que o que vai para o banco é apenas os selecionado. Simplesmente item.checked não é suficiente.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, vamos lá.

Essa foi a solução que eu encontrei em relação ao que eu entendi do seu problema.

Você tem uma lista de profissões já populada e a partir das seleções que o usuário fizer na mesma você quer salvar em algum tipo de storage.

Abaixo está o código que eu fiz para que todas as profissões selecionadas fossem armazenadas em uma lista específica.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    
    $scope.objeto = {
        profissoes: [
            {
                id: 1,
                nome: 'prof1',
                editando: false,
                selecionado: false
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                nome: 'prof2',
                editando: false,
                selecionado: false
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.profSelect = new Array();

    $scope.mudaLista = function(item){
        if(item.selecionado) {
            $scope.profSelect.push(item);
        } else {
            $scope.profSelect.splice(item, 1);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl as sic">
      <label class="requerido">Profissoes</label>
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="item in objeto.profissoes" ng-class="{'editando':item.editando}">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selecionado" ng-checked="item.selecionado" ng-change="mudaLista(item)"/>{{item.nome}}
         </li>
      </ul>
      <pre ng-bind="profSelect | json"></pre>
   </div>
</body>
```

Como você pode ver eu utilizei um `ng-change` para que a cada mudança (no caso a cada **check**) feita o sistema adiciona/remove a profissão da lista especifica para itens selecionados (**profSelect**).

A partir daí você já consegue armazena-la onde bem entender.

Espero ter ajudado :)